# VS Online Release definition | Paths

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am having difficulty trying to figure out what should be  the Value of “Package” field in the “Push Package to Octopus” step in the release definition. It is the value of the path from where all the packaged files are to be copied.

The value for the build definitions is mentioned below:

```
MSBuild Arguments
publishUrl="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\artifacts\Atea.Esb.Customers.Services.API"

Package |   Output Path
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\packages

Copy Publish Artifact    |   Copy Root
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Copy Publish Artifact    |   Artfact Name
Drop
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends where you've created your packages.

## Copy Files

**Source Folder:** `$(Build.sourcesDirectory)`

**Target Folder:** `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Content`

## Package Application

**Output Path:** `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

## Push Package(s) to Octopus

**Package:** `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*.nupkg`

Give those settings a whirl!

Comment: Thanks for taking out your precious time to answer my question .                          But the problem is still not resolved   I have tried the settings that you have shared but it has resulted in the below mentioned error.                                                  2017-10-04T13:51:28.7905043Z ##[error]Cannot find path 'C:\agent\_work\_tasks\OctopusPush_d05ad9a2-5d9e-4a1c-a887-14034334d6f2\2.0.78\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\' because it does not exist.

Comment: @Qasimupdated my answer to include a copy-files step; which should resolve the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: there is already a copy step whose values are shown above below Copy Files heading